# megacheck complains about a package exist in both vendors?

Tags: go, linter

git.domain.com/a/b/main.go:

```
import (
    "github.com/spf13/cobra"

    "git.domain.com/x/y/tlsgenerate"
)

func main() {
    rootCmd.AddCommand(tlsgenerate.CobraCommand)
}
```

git.domain.com/x/y/tlsgenerate/cmd.go:

```
package tlsgenerate

import (
    "github.com/spf13/cobra"
)

var CobraCommand = &cobra.Command{

}
```

and [gometalinter](https://github.com/alecthomas/gometalinter) said that:

> warning: cannot use tlsgenerate.CobraCommand (variable of type
>   *git.domain.com/x/y/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.Command) as *git.domain.com/a/b/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.Command value in argument to rootCmd.AddCommand (megacheck)

We use [dep](https://github.com/golang/dep) to manage dependency. And `github.com/spf13/cobra` exist in both `a/b/vendor` and `x/y/vendor`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Dep should "flatten" vendor directories to avoid precisely this problem. There should only be a single directory called vendor in the project tree. Is that not the case for you?

Comment: If I remove vendor in git.domain.com/x/y, then I got "warning: unused struct field cannot use tlsgenerate.CobraCommand (variable of type *invalid type) as *git.domain.com/a/b/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.Command value in argument to rootCmd.AddCommand (structcheck)". What's wrong?

Comment: Your single vendor directory should be at the top level of your project, or not all packages will use the same import.